# Parsing and Unmarshing CCD XML using Jaxb

Tags: cda, hl7-cda

I have a requirement to read and parse CCD xml in my application. It gave me error initially for `id` attribute which I solved by renaming ID attribute.

But when I try to unmarshal CCD xml to java obj from generated Java classes  I am  not getting the value for the java object

As CCD xml is quite complex. So what's the best way to parse CCD xml? I am open to use Java. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the MDHT CDA API
https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/modeling.mdht
You can download the latest runtime 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/oht-modeling/files/Releases/Runtime/
There is also the certification site which uses MDHT
https://sitenv.org

Answer (score 0):

Every time I have parsed a CDA/CCD I use directly XPath expressions to query content, for me this is the easiest and best performance solution.
Martí